# Using f suffix for numeric literals

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, math

I see some code like this:

```
float num2 = ( ( this.X * this.X ) + ( this.Y * this.Y ) ) + ( this.Z * this.Z );
float num = 1f / ( ( float ) Math.Sqrt ( ( double ) num2 ) );
this.X *= num;
this.Y *= num;
this.Z *= num;
```

Does it matter if it was like this?:

```
float num2 = ( ( this.X * this.X ) + ( this.Y * this.Y ) ) + ( this.Z * this.Z );
float num = 1 / ( ( float ) Math.Sqrt ( ( double ) num2 ) );
this.X *= num;
this.Y *= num;
this.Z *= num;
```

Would the compiler use `(float) / (float)` or try to use `(double) / (float)` for the 2nd example for line 2?

EDIT: Btw would there be any performance difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually uses `(int)/(float)` for the second example.  Since Int32 is implicitly convertible to Single, the compiler won't complain, and it will work fine.

That being said, it will complain if you do:

```
float num = 1.0 / ( ( float ) Math.Sqrt ( ( double ) num2 ) );
```

This would cause it to try to use `(double)/(float)`, which will effectively turn into `(double)/(double)`.  The compiler will then complain when that double is tried to be implicitly set into a float variable.

---

> EDIT: Btw would there be any performance difference?

Probably not a measurable one.  That being said, you're going to be creating extra conversion operations in IL.  These may get eliminated during JIT - but again, it'll be microscopic.

Personally, I would probably handle this using double precision math, since it would make the code easier to read:

```
double num2 = (this.X * this.X) + (this.Y * this.Y) + (this.Z * this.Z);
float num = (float) (1.0 / Math.Sqrt(num2));
this.X *= num;
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, also added another small question. Do you know that one?

Comment: @Joan: I edited...  BTW - my edit has far less conversion operations, too ;)

Comment: Thanks Reed. I agree, I also use double always. Just this code from 3rd party library confused me.

Comment: Btw what do you mean by "my edit has far less conversion operations, too"? :O Sorry didn't get the joke.

Answer (score 1):

No; it would be the same.

If you change `1f` to `1.0` (or `1d`), the result would be a `double`.

Comment: Thanks, also added another small question. Do you know that one?

Comment: @Joan: The speed of `double` vs. `float` operations depends on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, that makes sense/